Kotlin BroadcastReceiver Room Dao
I use the AlarmManager to send an Alarm and an BroadcastReceiver to get this Alarm.
My App also uses a Room Database with an NotificationDao.
I need to add something with "upsertNotification" to the Database when the Alarm is received.
How can I archive this?
BroadcastReceiver:
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val message = intent?.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE") ?: return
        val notificationType =
            NotificationType.fromValue(intent.getIntExtra("NOTIFICATION_TYPE", 0))

        val notification = Notification(
            id = null,
            date = LocalDate.now(),
            time = LocalTime.now(),
            title = "Test Title Premium",
            description = message,
            unread = true,
            notificationType = NotificationType.PremiumAdvertising.value
        )

        context?.let { DayReminderNotificationService(it) }?.showNotification(message)
    }
}

NotificationDao:
@Dao
interface NotificationDao {
    @Upsert
    suspend fun upsertNotification(notification: Notification)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteNotification(notification: Notification)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notifications")
    fun getAllNotifications(): Flow<List<Notification>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE unread = 1")
    fun getAllUnreadNotifications(): Flow<List<Notification>>
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object CoreModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideNotificationDao(database: AppDatabase) = database.notificationDao()
}

AlarmScheduler:
class AndroidAlarmSchedulerImpl(
    private val context: Context
) : AlarmScheduler {

    private val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(AlarmManager::class.java)

    override fun schedule(item: AlarmItem) {
        val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", item.message)
            putExtra("NOTIFICATION_TYPE", item.notificationType)
        }
        alarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            item.time.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond() * 1000,
            60000,
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                item.hashCode(),
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )

        )
    }

    override fun cancel(item: AlarmItem) {
        alarmManager.cancel(
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                item.hashCode(),
                Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
        )
    }
}


Please [edit] your question and also add the part where you let the DI framework inject the NotificationDao.

Thank you for your reply. I found a Solution now and postet it here. I don't know if this is the right way, but it works

I now found a solution. I don't know if it is the right way, but it works.
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AlarmModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAddDayReminderNotificationSingleton(
        notificationUseCases: NotificationUseCases,
        dayUseCases: DayUseCases
    ): AddDayReminderNotification {
        return AddDayReminderNotification(notificationUseCases, dayUseCases)
    }
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var addDayReminderNotificationSingleton: AddDayReminderNotification
...
}

@Singleton
class AddDayReminderNotification(
    private val notificationUseCases: NotificationUseCases,
    private val dayUseCases: DayUseCases
) {
...
}

